# Dropdown menu from html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I having a doubt with HTML tables. Is it possible to create a dropdown menu in a HTML table?
I want to display something like this:

```
1 video1 cam1  signal-present
2 video2 cam2  signal-present
3 video3 cam3  signal-present
```

When I click any of the row it should expand to give another set of rows like :

```
1 video1 cam1  signal-present
  -1 Audio1 source1 present
  -2 Audio1 source1 present
2 video2 cam2  signal-present
3 video3 cam3  signal-present
```

The table is populated using a Javascript. Is there better way to do this than tables.

Comment: Its better to go for javascript

Comment: All I did is add extra rows using a javascript, but it does look the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) functionality. There are tons of accordion plugins out there, but they all do the same thing:

**Working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7vX3S/5/

- Click class (this is what is shown by default)
- Content class (this is what shows when the `click class` is clicked

So, you would make the `<tr>` your `click class` and when a given `<tr>` is clicked you would have another `<tr>` slide down (expand).

jQuery:

```
  $(".clicker").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).next().hasClass("down")){
        $(this).next().slideUp("normal").removeClass("down");
    }
    else{
       $(this).next().slideDown("normal").addClass("down");
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr class="clicker">
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Some new data here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
tr.hidden{

    display: none;
}
```